# Disable computer on a schedule

Tags: windows, security, scripting

I'm looking for a way to disable end user access to a Windows 10 workstation during a given period, say, from 8pm to 8am.

It doesn't need to be superuser-proof.

It doesn't need to be reboot-proof.

Either a local program/script or a remote one or a group policy would do.

Either locking the screen or just disabling user input would do.

The best I've come up with is a script to lock the screen running every minute during the intended period, so that if someone unlocks the screen it won't be for long. But that's not an optimal solution.

edit: the workstation is not on Active Directory, but an AD-based solution may be welcome for other users.

Comment: Is the machine AD joined?

Comment: @vidarlo no, but if there's an AD way it may be interesting for others.